# ASP.NET MVC 5 app seed method crashes Visual Studio 2013 adding default user & role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-first

I'm building an MVC 5 app using Code First migrations and trying to seed my database with a default admin user.  I'm probably making the wrong assumptions here, but I assumed I need to use the async methods to add users and roles since I was getting errors about the user not existing earlier. Now it's crashing Visual Studio 2013 when I run the `update-database` command in the Package Manager Console. I'm at a loss.

I'm not getting an error before the crash and I haven't figured out how to debug code run in the PMC. Here's the code in my seed method:

```
        //Add default users here:
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var silkster = new NewUser() { UserName = "silkster", Password = "Passw0rd!", Email = "dan@silkster.com", Roles = new List<string>() { "Admin" } };

        var defaultUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(silkster.UserName);
        var newUserResult = IdentityResult.Success;

        if (defaultUser == null)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = silkster.UserName, Email = silkster.Email };
            newUserResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, silkster.Password);
        }

        if (newUserResult == IdentityResult.Success)
        {
            var results = new List<IdentityResult>();
            IdentityResult result;
            foreach (string role in silkster.Roles)
            {
                if (!RoleManager.RoleExists(role))
                {
                    result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                    results.Add(result);
                }
                result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(silkster.UserName, role);
                results.Add(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have extended the ApplicationUser with an Email field and I added a simple object, NewUser, to contain the seed data for a default user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280527/mvc5-seed-users-and-roles) that helped me resolve my Visual Studio crash issue.

Added this method to Configuration.cs:

```
    protected async Task<bool> AddRoleAndUser(ZTTDD.Models.ApplicationDbContext context, NewUser newUser)
    {
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        IdentityResult result = IdentityResult.Success; 

        var user = UserManager.FindByName(newUser.UserName);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = newUser.UserName, Email = newUser.Email };
            result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, newUser.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
                Console.Write("Unable to create user: " + newUser.UserName);
                return false;

        }

        foreach (string r in newUser.Roles)
        {
            if (!RoleManager.RoleExists(r))
            {
                var role = new IdentityRole(r);
                result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                    Console.Write("Unable to create role: " + r);
                    return false;
            }

            result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, r);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                Console.Write("Unable to add user '" + newUser.UserName + "' to role '" + r + "'.");
            }
        }

        return result.Succeeded;
    }
```

Then I refactored my code in the Seed method like so:

```
        var silkster = new NewUser() { UserName = "silkster", Password = "Passw0rd!", Email = "dan@silkster.com", Roles = new List<string>() { "Admin" } };
        var seedUserSuccess = await AddRoleAndUser(context, silkster);
        if (!seedUserSuccess)
        {
            Console.Write("Seeding failed for user: " + silkster.UserName);
        }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why the Conosle.Write() statements do not write to the PMC, even with the -verbose flag.

Comment: Also, the only issue I have left is the User is not Added to the Role.  Any Ideas?

Comment: New problem: changed this to loop through a List<NewUser>() and now that crashes VS2013.

Comment: doesn't visual studio give u compile time error when using `await` in a non-async method (`Seed`)