# MVC Identity Creating Roles and Assigning them to Users in Seed Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a MVC with Identity 1.0 web application. I'm trying to create and assign roles to my users during the first migration. I want the roles to display on AspNetRoles and the references from Roles to UserIds to display on AspNetUserRoles.

I'm trying to use this template here: [MVC 5 Seed Users and Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280527/mvc5-seed-users-and-roles)

`var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);` Gives me this error:

> 'MyModel.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'MyModel.Models.ApplicationUser' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.MyModel

`var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);` Gives me this error:

> The type 'MyModel.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserManager'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'MyModel.Models.ApplicationUser' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.

```
            manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
```

These two lines gives me this error:

> The name 'user' does not exist in the current context

```
    protected override void Seed(MyModel.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

        //Test Role
        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" };

            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "adminUser"))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);


            var passwordHash = new PasswordHasher();
            string password = passwordHash.HashPassword("Password@123");

            var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
        {

            new ApplicationUser { UserName = "adminUser", FirstMidName = "Admin", LastName = "Admin",Email="adminUser@gmail.com",PasswordHash = password,
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true,SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
            new ApplicationUser { UserName = "User", FirstMidName = "User", LastName = "User",Email="user@gmail.com",PasswordHash = password,
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-19"), DepartmentID = 2,DepotID = 2,IsAdministrator = false,SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
        };


            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.UserName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }
```

Comment: You don't have a variable named `user`. You created a list of users. But never a single instance.

Comment: So I can't have a list of users? I need to create something like user1 (Admin) and user2 (User) and use `manager.Create(user1,"ChangeItAsap!");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");` and             `manager.Create(user2, "ChangeItAsap!");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");`?

Comment: You can do it for individual users, but you never declared or assigned `user`. You need to do something like `var user = users[0];` before you can use the `user` variable. In this example, I set `user` to the first user in your list of `users`.