# Load file users into the AspNetUsers table

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, asp.net-identity

I have an Ms Excel file listing the users of my application. This file contains a set of informations of them(firstname, lastname, email...) but it does not contain the password and of course the Id fields. I want to load this file into the AspNetUsers table defined by the Ms Identity framework. How could i do this task?

thanks for your help

Comment: what i can suggest to you is to creat a task (maybe a test) wich ge items from excel and isert them in sql by EF

Comment: Good idea, thanks. But why should i use a task ? Is it for multi-threading purpose ?

Comment: Create a [seeding method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280527/mvc-5-seed-users-and-roles) in migration (or elsewhere). Read the file in, loop through it and add users as shown in link.

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution

Comment: If it help you i ll post it ad an answer and you can rate it if you want... thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i can suggest to you is to creat a consolen application or maybe a test Which can get the items from excel and isert them in sql by EF